# Java Guava Framework on ListenableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, future, guava

Is the below block of code valid? I saw this somewhere. But based on my own understanding, if we use immediateFuture to set the future to null upon construction.In theory, does the onSuccess code always execute, and it will never enter the onFailure block?

```
//public void doSomething(x,x){}
// doSomething(a,b)...

ListenableFuture<Void> future = Futures.immediateFuture(null);
            

Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<Void>(){
    public void onSuccess(@Nullable Void aVoid){
        //do something 
    }
    public void onFailure(@Nonnull Throwable throwable){
       //do something 
    }
    return future;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your code as posted isn't valid. Just to start with, `return future;` belongs outside the callback definition. It is always easier to get help here if you copy-paste code samples that you know actually compile and demonstrate the behavior you're asking about.

Second, yes, in your scenario `onSuccess()` would always be called as soon as you add the callback.

I'm not clear what this is for, though. If you clarify what you're trying to do we can provide more useful help.

Comment: hey I think it is a working code block, as it is in the production. This logic is written by my coworker and I don't understand it, even himself cannot explain it very well. So I am posting here. but my main question is that, in what scenario will the onFailure block be invoked, and is the onSuccess block in this case ALWASY invoked?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it really isn't syntactically valid Java. That free-floating return statement after the two callback methods but still inside the inner class declaration will break any Java compiler. If you don't believe me, try compiling it and let me know what happens. Note that you'll need to add a third `Executor` argument to `addCallback()` and close the braces and parens properly.

Comment: But, returning to your question: Yes, if you pass a future obtained from `Futures.immediateFuture()` to `Futures.addCallback()`, the callback's `onSuccess()` method will be called immediately, because the future is [already complete](https://guava.dev/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#addCallback-com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture-com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback-java.util.concurrent.Executor-).

Comment: Thanks, in other words onFailure will never be invoke ?

Comment: Yes, as I said, if you pass the value returned by `Futures.immediateFuture()` to `Futures.addCallback()`, the callback's `onSuccess()` method will always be called immediately. It is impossible for `onFailure()` to be called in this scenario.

Comment: what about the onSuccess throws some throwable exception, will it go to onFailure() block and do the invocation there? Thanks, sorry I am new to Guava and there's limited doc about this. The code is not written by myself while the author is not sure about that as well lol.